# How do I change 'Selects Code Structure' from cmd + click to a keybinding?

Tags: xcode, xcode11

I can't find any shortcut in the key-bindings list that will display this pop-up code actions menu. Is this strictly a click action only? Are there any potential workarounds for this?

[image: Code Actions]

I'm coming from vscode and I really loved being able to hit a keybinding and bring up all my code actions.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Update: I've discovered that the shortcut `show code actions` does work in a regular Xcode app project but not in a playground for some reason? Does anyone know why this would be?

Answer (score 0):

I am not pretty sure what is your intend but i would rather use to this one for your case,[image]

command click on code as jump to definition :)

Answer (score 0):

what you do in Vscode    `Ctrl+Click` is equal to `cmd+click` in Xcode

Comment: However in VS Code you can bind this to some keys. I guess this is just not possible in Xcode?

Comment: Thank you. I won't be accepting your answer as it's not the solution I was looking for. The keybinding for Show Code Actions works but not in Playgrounds for some reason. I submitted a bug report to Apple as I don't believe this was intentional